# expl3: peek_charcode_remove:NTF doesn't recognize \c_math_subscript_token

Tags: expl3

I have observed that the `\peek_charcode:NTF` and related functions do something unexpected. The functions do what I expect when the next character is `^` and I call, say,

```
\peek_charcode_remove:NTF \c_math_superscript_token
{ true code }
{ false code }
```

but the comparison fails if the next character is `_` and I call

```
\peek_charcode_remove:NTF \c_math_subscript_token
{ true code }
{ false code }
```

However, it works as expected using

```
\peek_charcode_remove:NTF _
{ true code }
{ false code }
```

Is this expected behavior?

This seems to happen regardless of whether the surrounding function is defined with `\cs_new:Nn` and variants or with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: Are you peeking at input that has `_` as catcode-8?

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand if you provided an example that showed the problem.

Comment: Should the title say 'subscript' rather than 'superscript'?

Comment: According to the documentation you can use `\c_math_superscript_token` for *category* code tests, but you're using it for *character* code tests, which you can't rely on!

Comment: Please note that your usage of `\c_math_superscript_token` just works "by accident" and you shouldn't rely on it behaving as it currently does in the future! So not only change your check for `_` but also your test for `^`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to peek for a character code, not for a category code. The token `\c_math_subscript_token` is guaranteed to have the meaning of a token of *category* math-subscript, but not guaranteed to have any specific *character* code (and currently, under pdfLaTeX it has the character code of `*` -- but don't rely on that as well!).

So this is just misuse of a documented token. If you want to test for a specific *character* code just use that character (provided it has no problematic category code that would make it an invalid `N`-type argument).

So to check if the next character is of the character code 95 (`_`), you can just use

```
\peek_charcode_remove:NTF _ {<true>} {<false>}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing---checking whether the next character after a particular command in user-space is "_" and acting accordingly. Thank you also for the warning about `\c_math_superscript_token` only working by accident. I think I actually *wanted* the `\peek_catcode_remove:NTF` function to do this, though the charcode comparisons with ^ and _ should work from user-space comparisons.